# Laravel 5 whereRaw result an error but the returned query runs fine in postgres client

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I get the error: **SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2** and the main problem is in `whereRaw()` function in that part of my code:

```
$result = $result->whereRaw(
    "lower(translate(?, ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')) LIKE lower(translate('%?%', ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc'))",
    [
        $field_where,
        $value
    ]
);
```

But when I get the **the result query** and run in my postgres client I get not errors.

So... whats the problem?

---

### Exception

```
SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not 
determine data type of parameter $2 (SQL: select count(*) as 
aggregate from "pace_records" left join "customers" on 
"customers"."id" = "pace_records"."customer_id" left join "cities"
on "cities"."id" = "customers"."city_id" left join 
"customer_subregions" on "customer_subregions"."id" = 
"pace_records"."customer_subregion_id" left join "schools" on 
"schools"."id" = "pace_records"."school_id" left join "programs" on 
"programs"."id" = "pace_records"."program_id" left join "users" on 
"users"."id" = "pace_records"."user_id" where 
"pace_records"."deleted_at" is null and 
lower(translate("cities"."name", ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')) LIKE 
lower(translate('%Arapi%', ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')))
```

### Full code

```
$result = static::joins();

if (isset(self::$searchable[$field])) {
    $field_where = $field;
    if (isset(self::$searchable[$field]['join_field'])) {
        $field_where = self::$searchable[$field]['join_field'];
    }

    $result = $result->whereRaw(
        "lower(translate(?, ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')) LIKE lower(translate('%?%', ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc'))",
        [
            $field_where,
            $value
        ]
    );
}

return $result->orderBy('cities.name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('schools.name', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('programs.name', 'ASC')
    ->paginate($maxPerPage);
```

---

### Infos

- Laravel 5.1.x
- PHP 5.6.x
- PostgreSQL 9.4
- Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.4

If you need more information, tell me.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the Postgres' unaccent extension http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/unaccent.html
The `ILIKE` operator is case insensitive.

Comment: The first whereRaw has only one parameter, the second question mark is enclosed by quotes.

Comment: Maybe your preg_replace is not returning what you are expecting, hence sending invalid parameter to the query.

Comment: @greg first, thanks for you answers. Please desconsider the if and else (I remove it). About the first `whereRaw`, if you look at the end of the first `whereRaw` parameter, I put the second parameter in the second `lower(`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the moment is concatenate the values instead of use params.

Like that:

```
    if (self::$searchable[$field]['type'] == 'LIKE') {
        $result = $result->whereRaw("lower(translate($field_where, ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')) 
        LIKE lower(translate('%$value%', ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc'))");
    } else {
        $result = $result->whereRaw("lower(translate($field_where, ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc')) 
        = lower(translate($value, ' ''àáâãäéèëêíìïîóòõöôúùüûçÇ', ' -aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucc'))");
    }
```

Works, but I don't like to do that.

I will keep search another solutions.